# Add column to Tweetdeck for all tweets sent out

Tags: twitter, tweetdeck

I currently have a column that contains a Twitter group/list containing only my twitter account.  However, this doesn't capture the reply or retweets I send.  They only contain basic original tweets.

Is there a way to add a column to Tweetdeck that **displays all tweets I make**?

It should basically look like the data in a user's twitter URL (example: twitter.com/user) where all sent tweets are shown (retweets, replies to specific user, etc).

Answer (score 4):

For anyone else finding this question via Google, Tweetdeck has apparently added some features in the 5 years since the question was first posted.

You can add a "User" column now to get all tweets and retweets that you yourself do. There's no need for a workaround using a "Search" column.

Answer (score 3):

Make a group in Twitter, add yourself on it and then add a column for this group on Tweetdeck.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a search column that is searching for your Twitter handle. That will show replies etc. But the downside is that it will only show tweets as far back as Twitter Search will return them.

Comment: I believe this is what I described and have set up. It doesn't show my retweets or my replies when I tweet to someone directly.